# How to clear image cache in Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm currently developing an app in Ionic 4 that use a lot of images from a host, using
`ion-img` like this

```
<ion-img src="http://example.com/imgs/1.jpg"></ion-img>
```

The problem is that all images that I load are saved in cache by default, making the app consume a lot of storage.
Also, if the image in the host changes, the app doesn't get the new one, as it have the old one saved in cache.

How can I clear the app cache?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cordova-plugin-cache-clear](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-cache-clear) to clear the entire cache from your app.

Comment: I've tried, but I don't know how to import it. I'm getting `error TS2339: Property 'CacheClear' does not exist on type 'Window'.` Is there any repository with an example on how to use this?

Answer (score 0):

I have this dependency [ion-media-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ion-media-cache). Soon I will be incorporating the service to maintain the cache. but if what you want is a maximum limit, you can customize it with maxCacheSize which is a size accumulator of the stored metadata.

```
<ion-img [url]="image" [customCache]="{maxCacheSize: 9999999999999999999}"></ion-img>
```